# Slow running stored procedure in SQL Server 2008 R2

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures, view

So it's rare that I get completely confused but wanted to see what others thought about what I'm experiencing.

I've been asked to look at a slow running stored procedure. Currently takes around 8-12 minutes to run.

So I noticed a useful index was missing and added it - now takes 8 seconds. But if I restart SQL Server and re-run the stored proc it's taking 8-12 minutes again.

If I then stop the query and delete the new index then re-run the stored proc it takes seconds again. Bizarre.

Has anyone ever experienced anything like this? The stored procedure is calling a View if that makes any difference.

Comment: Something related to cache?

Answer (score 1):

**Q.** `if I restart SQL Server and re-run the stored proc it's taking 8-12 minutes again.`

When you perform your query, the data is read into memory in blocks. These blocks remain in memory but they get "aged". This means the blocks are tagged with the last access and when Sql Server requires another block for a new query and the memory cache is full, the least recently used block (the oldest) is kicked out of memory. (In most cases - full tables scan blocks are instantly aged to prevent full table scans overrunning memory and choking the server).

**Q.** `If I then stop the query and delete the new index then re-run the stored proc it takes seconds again.`

What is happening here is that the data blocks in memory from the first query haven't been kicked out of memory yet so can be used for your second query, meaning disk access is avoided and performance is improved.

Comment: thanks for your quick response.. that kind of makes sense.. but if I restart SQL Server.. run the query and cancel it at around 10 seconds.. add the index and re-run it still completes within seconds.. restart SQL server again.. re-run the query and stop it at 30 seconds.. remove the index and it runs in seconds again!

Comment: Check the query's execution plan... Is there any difference with and without the index? I suspect that after you remove the index, the execution plan remains the same...

Comment: so I saved the execution plan as XML and compared using kdiff3 with and without the index.. appears to be quite a lot of difference

Comment: Before I post that I've done some further testing with some strange results.

1. Restart SQL server instance and run query (query time 10m >)
2. Add 1 of the two indexes the query plan suggests (takes 12 seconds)
3. Run query again (takes 2 seconds)
4. Call

CHECKPOINT;  
DBCC DROPCLEANBUFFERS; 

Rerun query (takes 12 seconds)
5. Run again (2 seconds)
6. Restart SQL server instance (10m > again)
7. Remove index added before restart (12 seconds)
If I restart the SQL server instance and run the query.. cancel it after a second of running, add or remove the index and run again it takes 12 seconds